# Transacciones dinámicas con datos desde servicios web

Tags: genexus

Estoy intentando hacer una transacción dinámica que obtiene datos desde un servicio web. Exactamente lo que dice en la página 14 de este documento: https://training.genexus.com/es/aprendiendo/pdf/data-providers-lenguaje-y-algunos-ejemplos-pdf

```
Data Provider = True
Used to = Retrieve data
Update Policy = Read Only (o Updatable, el resultado es el mismo)
```

Me da este error al hacer el build:

```
error: rgz0046: 'Input' clause is not supported in dynamic transaction Country and cannot be applied in element starting at row 6.
error: spc0173: Failed to specify DataProvider Country_DataProvider.
```

Hice una prueba muy parecida que en lugar de sacar los datos de un servicio web los saca de un segundo data provider que tiene elementos "harcodeados" y da el mismo error.

Estoy usando GX 17 U11, Java con Postgresql (también hice una prueba con sqlserver y pasa lo mismo).

Al parecer no es posible utilizar la cláusula "input" en una transacción dinámica.

¿Es esto correcto? De ser así, existe alguna forma de que la transacción dinámica utilize datos que no estén en una tabla ni estén "hardcodeados", sino que los obtenga dinámicamente desde fuera de la aplicación?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour], leas [ask] y agregues un [example] para que sea más fácil entender tu problema. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

¿qué tal? Se nos pasó al elaborar el material que la cláusula input no funciona cuando al trn es dinámica y se usa para recuperar datos (porque se crea una vista SQL en ese caso).
Vamos a modificar el ejemplo para que aplique solo a Data Providers no asociados a trn dinámica o asociados pero que no tienen el valor de Retrieve Data sino Populate.

Comment: Hola Cecilia, por favor lee [answer]. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour]

Comment: Ahhhh, ok! Entonces la pregunta es: teniendo una transacción normal, existe alguna forma de cambiarla o cambiar algo para que en lugar de obtener los datos de una tabla los obtenga de un servicio web? Haciendo también los cambios necesarios para que los insert, update y delete se hagan también a través de servicios.

Comment: GeneXus no soporta que el objeto transacción se base completamente en un servicio y los CRUD de la transacción vayan sobre ese servicio. Excepcionalmente sí soporta que las transacciones estén definidas sobre estructuras NoSQL (caso DynamoDB y CosmosDB) u ODATA.
Ref.: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?50498,DynamoDB+Support+in+GeneXus,
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?40713,OData+Support+in+GeneXus

Comment: Para interactuar con servicios externos, por ejemplo REST, puedes importar sus definiciones en la KB mediante https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?31864,OpenAPI+import+tool

Para crear sistemas donde múltiples kbs implementan subsistemas, te recomiendo estas charlas
https://www.genexus.com/es/productos/genexus/live2021/mission-critical-systems/modelado-de-arquitecturas-complejas-y-sistemas-de-mision-critica-con-genexus"
https://hub.genexus.com/es/webinar-xiku-complex-architectures-with-genexus

Comment: Gracias Cecilia. La idea es convertir la arquitectura de una KB preexistente que es relativamente compleja. La opción de OData tal vez podría servir, pero si Genexus no puede generar los servicios OData resulta una solución bastante “costosa” y difícil de mantener. Estoy llegando a la conclusión de que no es posible hacer una conversión sino que lo mejor sería re-implementar toda la KB desde cero.